# How to upload files to drive from Collab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, google-colaboratory, vcf-vcard

I want to know how we can upload the .txt & .vcf files.

I've already mounted the drive then done some sorting and downloading of data with wget in Collab. But I was not able to find resource to export or commit changes to drive.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 2):

Once you are inside a particular notebook, you can use the file browser on the left to upload files to be used the current notebook. Remember that they will be deleted once your current session ends, so you will have to upload them again when you open the notebook later. If you have uploaded them elsewhere, you can simply use `!wget` to download them to your notebook's temporary storage.

Edit: To copy data, simply use `!cp` to copy the file(s) from your notebook storage to the drive once you have mounted it. For example, here is how I would copy data.xyz:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
!cp data.xyz "gdrive/My Drive/data.xyz"
```

You may just as simply use `!mv` to move data to the drive instead of copying it. Just like that, you can copy/move data from the drive to the Collaboratory notebook too.

Comment: I need to export the data from colab to drive, not from other place to colab notebook!!!!

Comment: Use `!cp` to copy the file(s) to your mounted drive. Look at my updated answer.